# Is there a website where I can buy wholesale travels?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, tours, travel-agents, group-travel

I want to travel with my friends and family but a want to travel agency price.

Comment: Do you mean like group bookings? You're taking 20 people?

Comment: Yes, More or less.

Answer (score 11):

There really isn't a "travel agency" price anymore. Travel agencies get a commission (small) for everything they sell at retail prices. They don't buy cheap and add on profit margins.

Travel agents can avail themselves to industry pricing sometimes, but that is only for themselves and usually is dependent on how much they sold for that company the year before. All the hype you see about traveling for free or cheap if you are a "travel agent" is simply marketing hype from card mills, selling dodgy travel agent IDs.

If you have a reasonable size group (8 people or more), you can sometimes get group rates from tour companies.  With 10 or more rooms you can sometimes get group rates from hotels.

If you have larger groups you can ask for group rates from airlines.  Group rate airfares are not really any cheaper than what you can find on their websites, but group fares sometimes have more flexibility.

You don't need to be a travel agent to get group rates, simply contact the hotel, tour company or airline and ask what they may have available.